# USB to Serial emulation

Tags: serial-port, usb, usbserial

I bought this magnetic strip reader writer (MSRE106) and I use USB adapter to connect it to my laptop because I have no serial port in my computer. But now I have a problem since the software of the device recognizes only serial ports on windows. After looking up I found someone that wrote a python script for Linux (found here [The Script](http://sourceforge.net/projects/msr106205/files/)).

Still even in this python script in the settings file it has this variable

```
## Com port.
COM = "COM1"
```

How can I change this to be one of my USB ports instead of a serial one because I have none

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This script is made to use serial port as well, which means you can't just modify COM="USB1" or whatever to use your USB adapter. If you have a look at line 264 a serial port is open using function SerialPort().

To fix this issue you must install your USB adapter's driver that will emulate a serial port and create a fake COM1 you can use with this script or the original software of the MSRE106.

Comment: I see what you mean thats right, but if you don't mind putting me on the right path, how can I emulate a usb to a COM1 port I am not really that professional. From where can I start ?

Comment: Tell me what USB adapter you've got.